# API facebook don't publish feed on page

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to publish feeds on the Facebook Page by API. I have followed the facebook documentation creating app in the facebook developer. Before I have registered a account facebook (example: test_account) and after that I have created the page for the business activity (example: test_page) where the manage admin is "test_account". 
I have gone to the API by Graph API Explorer

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I have granted the "**publish_actions**" and taken the access token generated by interface tool as followed image

[image]

After that I have tried the call POST request to test the publish feeds on the page facebook (test_page) by

> https://graph.facebook.com/{id_page_business}/feed?message=test_message&access_token={access_token_APP}

and I have received the new ID_feed and I have seen the feed on facebook page and OK, but the access token the day after was expired. How can I have the access token that don't expired ?
I have tried another solution to obtain the access token from the call GET request (as documentation)

**(STEP 1)**
[image]

so I have obtained access token associated to the APP (see below)

access_token={APP_ID}|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxjw

**(STEP 2)** I have sended call GET request

> https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}/accounts?access_token=APP_ID}|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxjw

and I have obtained the followed response:

```
 {
  data: [1]
       0:  {
          id: "xxxxxxxx"
          login_url: "https://developers.facebook.com/checkpoint/test-user-login /132173517148280/"
          access_token: "123456........"
}

paging: {
cursors: {
before: "yMTczNTE3MTQ4Mjgw"
after: "yMTczNTE3MTQ4Mjgw"
}
}
}
```

(STEP 3) So I have tried the call POST request to publish the feed on the facebook page with the last access token (123456........) and I have received

```
{
id: "1256xxxxxx_133346xxxxxx"
}
```

but in the page business I don't see the feed... WHY?
**IMPORTANT**:I have noticed if I call the request GET API to obtain all feeds page (https://graph.facebook.com/ID_PAGE/feed?access_token=CAAPG1DFdxrs...........) I can see the feeds published, but into the facebook interface timeline I don't see the feed.
I have noticed that the feed publish by API return:

```
message: "test"
created_time: "2015-11-29T16:39:44+0000"
id: "APP_ID_138999329797136"
```

The second part the id is different respect when I publish the feed with access token get from the API Graph.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have extended token on page access token to post on the page. App access token will provide you all read access to the page but will not allow you to post.

Below steps must help -

1. Get the page access token using -

   > https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}/accounts?access_token={APP_ID}|xxxxxxxxxxxx
2. Using the page access token obtain the extended token, below is how I had implemented using VB.NET

   > Dim parameters As Object = New ExpandoObject()  
   >   parameters.client_id = FB_APP_ID  
   >   parameters.client_secret = FB_APP_SECRET  
   >   parameters.grant_type = "fb_exchange_token"  
   >   parameters.fb_exchange_token = short_token 'FBClient.AccessToken  
   >   Dim result As Object = FBClient.Get("oauth/access_token", parameters)

Use this extended token to post on page. It worked for me, hope it helps you.

Comment: The extended token is valid for 60 days, but how do I refresh token after 60 day without login? because I have the cron server side that active a workflow to publish all feeds on the facebook page business by APP, I don't have interface in front end. The strange thing that I don't understood is that I have done the procedure calls request that I described above and publish the feed, but the string get seems old and so I don't see into the facebook page business. Instead if call the API GET feed I can see the feed posted. WHY?